# Curl is allowing POST requests but browser is not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I am trying to develop an API that allow POST request of file data, but the POST request only functions using curl `curl -X POST --data file= mouse.fa "http://localhost:3000/api/data?file=mouse.fa"` . When I trying a POST request in the browser, I get a GET error `Cannot GET /api/data`. Please could you advise me on how to get the POST request to work in the browser in addition to curl.

router.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

fileParser = require("./fileParser")
router.use('./fileParser', fileParser.parse);

// middleware
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('Received request');
    next();
});


router.post('/data', function (req, res) {
    //Check file is valid
    if (!req.body.file.toString().endsWith('.fa')) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: "Bad Request" });
    } else {
        fileParser.parse(`./${req.body.file.toString()}`);
        res.json({ message: "File parsed and data submitted.", location: "/data/" });
    }
    
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');

// create server
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Server running at ${port}`)
});

// import router
const router = require('./router');
app.use('/api', router)
```

Comment: Post a code snippet demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What kind of error does you get?

Comment: @Stephen ```Cannot GET /api/data.```

Comment: From the error, it looks like you're doing GET instead of POST. Maybe add the code of how you perform the request from the browser, and we could tell if there's an issue there.

Comment: @Basa Thanks for your reply, I am performing the request like this ```http://localhost:3000/api/data?file=mouse.fa```

Comment: Are you just opening the URL in the browser? This will always lead to a GET request. You need to submit a form, marked with POST or do an XHR request with JavaScript to make a POST from the browser...

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Ok, right I understand now. So I need to use XMLHttpRequest class? Sorry, I am new to API development and http protocols.

Comment: If you want to access an API from JavaScript, it's probably easier to just use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which is supported in newer browsers. You could also use the library `axios`, which supports more features. Keep in mind that the browser does not like cross-origin requests (e.g. from localhost:8080 to localhost:9090) and you'll need a reverse proxy or an appropriate CORS config, otherwise you will run into the next problem. You could also just serve the HTML on the same server to avoid that problem.